# osquery suid_bin usage to list all system suid bit set

Tags: sql, request, suid, osquery

I have to list all suid set on my server with osquery, I assume that suid_bin should give me all suid set, but it seems that it misses some of them.
I'm using it like this:

```sql
Select * from suid_bin
```

But if I do a manual check on /usr for example I have some that are not in my previous results. To manual check a specific folder I'm using the following request:

```sql
SELECT * FROM file WHERE path LIKE "/usr/%%" and mode like "4755";
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm learning on osquery for now so I'm not comfortable with request on it...

Answer (score 2):

This is the documented behavior.

Looking across an entire filesystem is an expensive operation. So, as described in the [schema](https://osquery.io/schema/4.2.0), the `suid_bin` table looks for suid binaries in *common locations*, not exhaustively. If you want to see the list of places it looks, it's in the [source code](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/blob/e6fe15eb49660725e65dba1549932ed96e0a8c6e/osquery/tables/system/posix/suid_bin.cpp#L24-L26)

As you discovered, the `file` table will let you recursively search the filesystem.